# Using DataProvider in ReactAdmin, how to fix an errorr: the expected type comes from the return type of this signature

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I'm following the tutorial to implement dataprovider in react-admin. Here is the link: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#connecting-to-a-real-api

Below is the sample implementation of tutorial

```
  create: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
    }).then(({ json }) => ({
        data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
    })),
```

But in typescript it raise an error the expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: From the [React Admin Discord server](https://discord.gg/GeZF9sqh3N):
I might be wrong but I believe by default RA will expect `id` to be of type `Identifier`, i.e. either a `string` or a `number`. You can either provide the `ResultRecordType` parameter type with your own type, or tell TS that the returned `id` is a `string` or a `number` (based on your backend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [PR](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/9501), you could type `data` with `any` as follows:

```
create: (resource, params) =>
    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
    }).then(({ json }) => ({
        data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } as any,
    })),
```

It should fix the TS error you're facing.